# Server not receiving client's socket.io message

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I started a simple express+socket.io project.
On the server I registered to socket's 'connection' event and upon that I send a message to the client. This works well.

When I receive the message on client side from the server, in this event handler i do socket.emit('message', 'some text');

This message doens't arrive to server.
I know it should be very simple and thus I think i missing something stupid.
Any help appreciated.

server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    io.emit('server-message', 'hello socket.io server');
});

io.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

client code:

```
window.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('server-message', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
            socket.emit('message', 'hello socket.io from browser');
         });
```

Comment: I found a very tricky thing, hope your timezone and time on a simulator is right when you do real time! otherwise it eat messages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `io.emit('server-message', 'hello socket.io server');` should be changed to `socket.emit('server-message', 'hello socket.io server');` You would then need to move the following into the `connection` event listener:

```
io.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

and change it to

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: you opened my eyes! i didn't understand where do i get the socket object on the server. Then I searched a bit and found the 'connection' event has it and there the subscription should be made. thanks!

Comment: I was wondering why you changed the io.on to socket.on, and then realized that the argument from `io.on('connection', function (socket)` is why.  I don't know why, but this wasn't super obvious from the docs, even though it's right in there.  Seems like a common mistake for noobs, but really hard to find the answer if you don't understand how it's working.